# How to change a CSS attribute of keyframes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-selectors

I have 2 selectors `from` and `to` inside of `@keyframes` scope like this:

```
@keyframes pie {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 77px;
    }
}
```

I would like to change `to`'s attribute through JavaScript, but seems like giving `style` property to `.pie` doesn't work as I wanted it. It creates the attribute to `.pie` directly instead of `to` selector.

This is how I've done so far:

```js
class Timer {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.elem = document.querySelector(elem);
        this.change();
    }
    change() {
        this.elem.style.strokeDashoffset = 10 + 'px';
    }
}
let getTimer = new Timer('.pie');
```

```css
svg.timer {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(-90deg);
}
circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 77px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke: brown;
    animation: pie 10s linear infinite forwards;
}
@keyframes pie {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 77px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="pie">
    <svg class="timer">
        <circle r="12" cx="20" cy="20">
        </circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Are there any ways to change the `attribute` inside of `to` selector through Javascript?

Comment: have you considered using css variables?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971942/change-strokedashoffset-of-a-svg-line-in-a-for-loop

Comment: @AdamOrlov I think the link you've given doesn't relate with my case. My major problem is to give or change the attribute that is inside of `@keyframes selectors`. The OP from your link doesn't use `@keyframes` or any selectors in CSS.

Comment: @Bravo I set the attribute as `stroke-dashoffset: var(LGdashOffset)` in CSS, and tried to change my code in JS like this: `document.documentElement.style.LGdashOffset = 101 + 'px';` But still the attribute of `to` selector didn't change.

Comment: `var(LGdashOffset)` isn't how you use css vars in CSS... and `document.documentElement.style.LGdashOffset = 101 + 'px'` isn't how you change them!! here's how I learned https://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use [CSS-variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties):

```js
class Timer {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.elem = document.querySelector(elem);
        this.change();
    }
    change() {
        this.elem.style.setProperty('--dashoffset',  10 + 'px');
    }
}
let getTimer = new Timer('.pie');
```

```css
svg.timer {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(-90deg);
}
circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 77px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke: brown;
    animation: pie 10s linear infinite forwards;
}
@keyframes pie {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 77px;
        stroke-dashoffset: var(--dashoffset);
    }
}
.pie { --dashoffset: 77px; }
```

```html
<div class="pie">
    <svg class="timer">
        <circle r="12" cx="20" cy="20">
        </circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```

However its support is still not that great, and it's really hard to polyfill so if you have to handle legacy browsers, you may need to rewrite the rule directly, by appending a new <style> with the whole @keyframes block:

```js
class Timer {
    constructor(elem) {
      this.elem = document.querySelector(elem);
      this.change();
    }
    change() {
      const style = document.createElement('style');
      style.textContent = `
@keyframes pie {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: ${ 10 }px;
  }
}`
      document.head.appendChild( style );
    }
}
let getTimer = new Timer('.pie');
```

```css
svg.timer {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(-90deg);
}
circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 77px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke: brown;
    animation: pie 10s linear infinite forwards;
}
@keyframes pie {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 77px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="pie">
    <svg class="timer">
        <circle r="12" cx="20" cy="20">
        </circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```